# Bootstrap with fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullpage.js

Hey i am pretty new to both bootstrap and fullpage.js, the issue i am having is the want to load multiple images using the grid system from bootstrap within one of my sections, i currently have multiple sections working however this issue with images has proved a bump in my road.

```
<div class="section">

            <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
            <h1>Tree Kangaroos</h1>
            <p>What are they exactly?</p>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col1-sm-4">
            <img src="images/face.png" />
            </div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col1-sm4">
                    <img src="images/face.png" />
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>





        </div>
```

This is the code i am having trouble with, everything else implemented so far with fullpage is working and there is no java script included with bootstrap(to my knowledge) so i have not shown the entirety of my code as its rather large my jumbotron is also working so i'm guessing bootstrap is working as intended and the issue is with my coding itself.

The exact issue is that my images stack on top of each other rather than horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with your columns those are not valid bootstrap classes..

Col-md-4 is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you this worked, programming really makes me feel dumb sometimes.